# Powershell find Always On protection status in Recovery Service Vault

Tags: azure, powershell

I am writing a powershell script to check the backup items for SQL VM in the Recovery service vault. My script looks like below, it loops through the subscription and find all Vaults and then all container in those vaults and list the backup items. However, it only return instance backups, not Always On backups.

```
$Subscritions=Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object {$_.name -like "abc1*"}
foreach ($subscition in $Subscritions)
{

$subscition |Set-AzContext

     $vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault 
     foreach($vault in $vaults)
     {
         $Containers =Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVMAppContainer" -Status "Registered" -VaultId $vault.ID 
                 foreach ($container in $Containers )
                 {
                 $backupitem=Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType MSSQL -VaultId $vault.ID
                  $backupitem |select -Property friendlyname, SErvername |ft
                 } 
               
        # $backupitem=$backupitem |select -Property ServerName,name, ProtectionStatus, LastBackupTime,LatestRecoveryPoint,ProtectionState,LastBackupErrorDetail,LastBackupStatus| out-datatable
        # Write-DataTable  -Data $backupitem  -ServerInstance localhost-Database t1 -TableName dbo.BackupStatus 
     }
```

Comment: [1] it looks like you are missing some of your code. at least the closing `}` for the 1st `foreach` is missing. ///// [2] did you REALLY misspell `subscription` _two different ways_ in your code? [*grin*]

Comment: yeah, good point, I did misspell. but that is not the point. the point here is what we can use the GUI to figure out the backup status of the instance backup and AG backup, but we are not able to find any AG backup using the code.

Comment: it would be wise of you to fix your code. as it is, the glitches are distracting from the actual problem. [*grin*] ///// since i have no access to the AZ stuff, i will go back to lurking ... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem` will return all backup items. If you want to check the type of the item, please check `parentName`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/2021-02-10/backup-protected-items/list#azurevmworkloadsqldatabaseprotecteditem) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/get-azrecoveryservicesbackupitem?view=azps-6.0.0)